# unable to write on sitemap.xml (permission denied)

Tags: aem

I am trying to update the sitemap.xml file under "/" . I am getting an error of permission denied, below is the snippet of code.

```
 XMLOutputFactory outputFactory = XMLOutputFactory.newFactory();
        try {
            Session session = repository.loginAdministrative(null);
            XMLStreamWriter stream = outputFactory.createXMLStreamWriter(new FileWriter("/sitemap.xml"));
            stream.writeStartDocument("1.0");
            stream.writeStartElement("", "urlset", NS);
            stream.writeNamespace("", NS);
            write(page, stream, resourceResolver);
            for (Iterator<Page> children = page.listChildren(new PageFilter(), true); children.hasNext();) {
                write(children.next(), stream, resourceResolver);
            }
            stream.writeEndElement();
            stream.writeEndDocument();
            session.save();
        } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception ioex){
            logger.error(ioex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Even i also have set the permission inside JCR for this file, contributors to jcr:all access. But still getting permission denied error.

Thanks

Comment: There is an implementation of sitemap generator in the ACS commons package , http://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/simple-sitemap.html , give it a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following line:

```
XMLStreamWriter stream = outputFactory.createXMLStreamWriter(new FileWriter("/sitemap.xml"));
```

creates a file in the filesystem, not a node in the JCR repository. In order to save the result to the JCR node, first write it to a ByteArrayOutputStream and then use JCR API to write the buffer to a new node:

```
// ByteArrayOutputStream bos already contains the serialized sitemap
ValueFactory vf = session.getValueFactor();
Binary binary = vf.createBinary(new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray()));

Node rootNode = session.getRootNode();
Node sitemapNode = rootNode.addNode("sitemap.xml", "nt:file");
Node resNode= sitemapNode.addNode("jcr:content", "nt:resource");
resNode.setProperty ("jcr:data", binary);
session.save();
```

Please notice, that the root node (`/`) is probably not the best place to write anything. You should write your map somewhere in the `/content` and use Sling Mappings, a custom servlet or a filter to handle the `/sitemap.xml` path.

Comment: Thanks its worked, Can you tell me scnerion about sling mapping to handle sitemap

Answer (score 0):

You need **root** permission to edit `/sitemap.xml`. Have you tried `sudo`?

I guess you want to edit the XML *in your program directory*, so use `./sitemap.xml`.

Comment: I created a sitemap.xml file under my jcr_root directory of my codebase. and added   <filter root="sitemap.xml" /> . Have set the permission 777 to full path till sitemap.xml & build. Still my sitemap.xml not going inside JCR say under "/". Thanks

Comment: oh missed It should be <filter root="/sitemap.xml" />

Comment: If i use outputFactory.createXMLStreamWriter(new FileWriter("/sitemap.xml")); then i am getting permission denied again. & if i use file path as ./sitemap, then it shows no error seems execution completed, but no content inside sitemap.xml

Comment: @VDhim I think it may be wrong with your saving code, but not the location if u use `./`